# Error with post-build event command

Tags: .net, visual-studio, post-build-event, build-events

I get an error, while compiling my C#-code with Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7.

I have these Build Events (Post-build Event Command Line):

```
if not "$(ConfigurationName)"=="Release" goto :finish 
"$(TargetDir)mt.exe" -manifest "$(ProjectDir)$(TargetName).exe.manifest" –outputresource:"$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)";#1
"$(ProjectDir)ILMerge.exe" /out:"$(TargetDir)Merged\Software.exe" "$(TargetPath)" "$(ProjectDir)bin\x86\Dlls\mwc.dll" "$(ProjectDir)bin\x86\Dlls\Interop.Access.dll" "$(ProjectDir)bin\x86\Dlls\Interop.DAO.dll"
:finish
```

If I remove: `$(ProjectDir)bin\x86\Dlls\Interop.Access.dll` everything is fine. With this code, I get this error if I rebuild my code:

> exited with code 1.

I think it didn't find the dll-file, but it is there. I have checked it for many times...

I have no idea how to fix that.

@edit: sorry, i've made a mistake, this is the right code now... it does'nt work anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a closing quote at the end of the `$(ProjectDir)bin\x86\Dlls\Interop.Access.dll`

```
"$(ProjectDir)ILMerge.exe" /out:"$(TargetDir)Merged\Software.exe" "$(TargetPath)" "$(ProjectDir)bin\x86\Dlls\mwc.dll" "$(ProjectDir)bin\x86\Dlls\Interop.Access.dll "$(ProjectDir)bin\x86\Dlls\Interop.DAO.dll"
```

Should be...

```
"$(ProjectDir)ILMerge.exe" /out:"$(TargetDir)Merged\Software.exe" "$(TargetPath)" "$(ProjectDir)bin\x86\Dlls\mwc.dll" "$(ProjectDir)bin\x86\Dlls\Interop.Access.dll" "$(ProjectDir)bin\x86\Dlls\Interop.DAO.dll"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to debug `post-build` scripts. 
One of possible ways, I personally use, is execute suspicios line(s) separately in console and hopefully get more detailed explanation of what is going on there.

So try, for example, exeute `ILMerge` with the command line arguments you use in post build event, and see what happens.

Good luck.

Comment: When I try to execute ilmerge i get "exited with code 9009" error - what could this be?